# Pass a parameter to OWIN host

Tags: c#, owin

I'm self-hosting ASP.NET Web API and SignalR using OWIN. I start the server (on a console app) with this code:

```
using (WebApplication.Start<Startup>(url))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This works fine. But now I need to pass a parameter (an object) to the `Startup` class. How can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `WebApplication.Start` method has an overload that accepts a `IServiceProvider` as parameter, so it is possible to inject the data I want.

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = DefaultServices.Create(defaultServiceProvider =>
{
    defaultServiceProvider.AddInstance<IMyInterface>(myInstance);
});

using (WebApplication.Start<Startup>(serviceProvider, url)){ ... }
```

Now, on my `Startup` class I only need to create a constructor that receives the IMyInterface:

```
public Startup(IMyInterface myInstance)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`WebApp.Start Method (String, Action<IAppBuilder>)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.hosting.webapp.start(v=vs.113).aspx#M:Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start%28System.String,System.Action%7BOwin.IAppBuilder%7D%29).

Example:

```
using (WebApplication.Start(url, appBuilder => new Startup(myObject).Configuration(appBuilder)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```