# Hw to pass arguments to my own Startup class?

Tags: c#, owin

I'm trying to develop a web api self hosting app using OWIN.
In my own XyzStartup class, I need an external argument: contentFolderPath.

However, I didn't find a way to pass this argument. Here is my code below:

```
var contentFolderPath = this.TextBox.Text; // user input

var startOptions = new StartOptions();
using(WebApp.Start<XyzStartup>(startOptions)){

}
```

My startup

```
public class XyzStartup
{
     XyzStartup(string contentFolderPath) {  ...  }
}
```

I noticed there is a StartOption class, but don't how to use it. Can I use it in my XyzStartup class?

Thanks in advance!

---

I finally find a way to do this:

```
var startOptions = new StartOptions();
startOptions.Urls.Add('..some url ..');

WebApp.Start(startOptions, (appBuilder)=>{
    new XyzStartup(contentFolderPath).Configuration(appBuilder);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a parameter to OWIN host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511651/pass-a-parameter-to-owin-host)

Answer (score 27):

If you want to pass parameter to StartUp class, you can use `Action<IAppBuilder>` in WebApp.Start like Cillié Malan mentioned in the comment instead of launching with Type parameter(`WebApp.Start<T>`)

Here is a concrete example for self-hosting:

```cs
object someThingYouWantToAccess;
var server = WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080/", (appBuilder) =>
{
    // You can access someThingYouWantToAccess here

    // Configure Web API for self-host.
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, though it may have been possible before, it is not possible to pass parameters to the startup class.

However, when self hosting, I noticed that the startup class is created in the same thread that calls `WebApp.Start`. With this in mind I used a `ThreadStatic` field to pass information to the startup class (in my case I wanted to pass `HttpConfiguration`):

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        private HttpConfiguration _configuration;

        [ThreadStatic]
        internal static HttpConfiguration _configurationHolder;

        public static HttpConfiguration CurrentConfiguration
        {
            get { return _configurationHolder; }
            set { _configurationHolder = value; }
        }

        public Startup()
        {
            //get the configuration which is held in a threadstatic variable
            _configuration = _configurationHolder;
        }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

And then elsewhere I have another method that starts the self-hosted site:

```cs
    public void Start(StartOptions startupOptions, HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Startup.CurrentConfiguration = configuration;
        _application = WebApp.Start<Startup>(startupOptions);
        Startup.CurrentConfiguration = null;
    }
```

Comment: Also, I just noticed that there is an overload for `WebApp.Start` that accepts `Action<IAppBuilder>`, in which case you can just capture any parameters you might need.